# Is this a Maori interlocution at the beginning of Chlöe Swarbrick's speech? What is its significance?

Tags: parliament, languages, new-zealand

At the beginning of a [speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxJsPXrEqCI) that became notorious for an entirely different reason, MP Chlöe Swarbrick appears to say something unintelligible in English, which I presume could be a Maori interlocution. (Maori [is sometimes spoken](https://nzhistory.govt.nz/politics/the-work-of-government/history-of-parliament/parliament-in-te-reo) in the New Zealand parliament.) Basically, what is she saying before "Mr. Speaker" and why is she (seemingly) not saying it in English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A draft transcript of the speech (all the speeches) is available.

[Climate Change Response (Zero Carbon) Amendment Bill — Second Reading](https://www.parliament.nz/en/pb/hansard-debates/rhr/combined/HansDeb_20191105_20191105_12)

> CHLÖE SWARBRICK (Green): E Te Māngai, tēnā koe. Tēnā koutou e Te Whare.

Google translate: Mr. Speaker, thank you. Greetings to the House.

Comment: It seems to be a bit of a tradition of the Greens to open with a greeting in Maori. See e.g. their leader's speech on another occasion https://www.greens.org.nz/news/press-release/commencement-speech-start-parliament-2019